# Pass Freeradius Username and Password to external php file

Tags: php, variables, freeradius

i've a problem with fetch username,password from the freeradius
i've edited default and putted :
authorize {

```
update control { 
             Auth-Type := `/usr/bin/php /etc/raddb/file.php %{User-Name} %{User-Password}`
        }
```

now how does file.php see the username and password ?
i tried both get,post and even request and still null and nothing to view
so ..

How can i pass these variables to my php file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution ... 
it's by putting -q to command line and fetch all with $argv